# How to check array is empty in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have one array of array.I want check my inner array is empty or not.and I am checking objects of array are empty string.
Here is my code :

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *selectArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < [newArray count]; i++)
{
    NSArray *arr = [newArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([arr count] > 0)
    {
        NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:0];

        if (![str isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            [selectArray addObject:str];
        }
    }
}
```

my newArray is array of array.I want to add strings in selectArray which are not empty.but, only 0th index object is added in selectArray multiple times.
Please suggest me, where i am doing wrong.thanks

Comment: I think above code is correct. Can you please confirm what the result after execution above code. Can you please try "NSMutableArray *selectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];"

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you are just getting the 0'th element of your newArray's elements, I mean this line

```
NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
```

you should put another for in your code. Use this code instead of yours

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *selectArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < [newArray count]; i++){
    NSArray *arr = [newArray objectAtIndex:i];

    for (int j = 0; j < [arr count]; j++){
        NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:j];

        if (![str isEqualToString:@""]){
            [selectArray addObject:str];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code You not need to create any extra variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [newArray count]; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < [[newArray objectAtIndex:i] count]; j++)
    {
        if (![[[newArray objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            [selectArray addObject:str];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following generic function to check any of the value or object is empty or null.

```
-(BOOL)isEmpty:(id)object{
    return object == nil
    || [object isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]
    || ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(length)]
        && [(NSData *)object length] == 0)
    || ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(count)]
        && [(NSArray *)object count] == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *selectArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSArray *arrayFromNewArray in newArray) {
        if ([arrayFromNewArray count] > 0)
        {
            NSString *str = [arrayFromNewArray firstObject];

            if (![str isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                [selectArray addObject:str];
            }
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *selectArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (int i = 0; i < [newArray count]; i++)
{
NSArray *arr = [newArray objectAtIndex:i];

for (int j = 0; j < [arr count]; j++)
{
    NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:j];

    if (![str isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        [selectArray addObject:str];
    }
}
}
```

Problem is you forgot the second loop :) Let me know if I am correct.